# Why when django picks up data from Mysql, the data shown on the html is messy code

Tags: mysql, django

Here's my views.py code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
#import chardet
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

from django.shortcuts import render
import MySQLdb

def myview(request):

    db = MySQLdb.connect(
        host = 'localhost',
        port = 3306,
        user = 'root',
        passwd = '123',
        db = 'new_gkgw',
        )

    cur = db.cursor()
    db.commit()
    aa = cur.execute("select * from shici")
    bb = cur.fetchmany(aa)

    return render(request, 'dict/mytemplate.html', {"rows": bb})
```

here's my template's code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        {% for row in rows %}
            <li>{{ row }}</li>  
        {%  endfor %}       
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine = INNODB
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_bin

[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
init_connect = 'set names utf8mb4'
```

And here is some messy code shown on html, it's really messy.

(1L, '?', '1.?????????(???????)', '2.????????????(?)?????(?)?????????????', '3.????????(?)???????????????', None, None, None, None, None, None)

Help me please....

Comment: You tagged this with Django. Are you doing this in Django? If so, why not use ORM?

Comment: @zanderle yes zanderle, i do that in Django. ORM seems new to me. thanks for reminds. I will search for it right now. :-)

Comment: @zanderle i got what you mean. But what i want is to pick up data from my existing database. I don't want to create a new model

Comment: Have you seen this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: @zanderle so you mean that i have to use ORM ?

Comment: You don't *have* to, but since you're using Django, it wouldn't make sense not to use it. If you're not going to use it, I would argue a different framework might be more appropriate for you.

Comment: @zanderle i got your intention. But if i use ORM, Does it mean that i have to insert all the data one by one?

Comment: Insert it from where? You can do it programmatically - either in shell/script or as a datamigration